# Is there a way to import or convert vmware player images to run on xen?

Tags: vmware, xen, vmware-player

It's fairly popular for companies offering a quick way to test their product to give you a vmware player image.  I don't run VMWare though, I run Xen exclusively.

Most of these images (and the one I'm interested right this moment particularly) are linux images.  Is there a way to use this image with Xen?  Obviously, I could setup player long enough to boot the image, then move the data out of the image to a Xen image, but I'm hoping for something easier and quicker than that...preferably that doesn't require setting up a box to run player than can run this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*sigh*](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+vmware+image+to+xen)

Comment: Hmmm...I guess I didn't read those closely enough.  I tried several searches, but not knowing much about vmware, I saw the references to vmdk images and assumed I wasn't getting what I wanted.  (This is a vmx image).  But looking deeper I guess they do address that in some of these links.

Thanks for the help anyway.